# How to call php array twice without losing results?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE...";
$result = $db->query($qry);
$if($db->error)die($db->error);
```

This returns an array of 15 students. My code then continues as such:

```
$faculty= $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($faculty['field'] == 1)
    die();

while($students = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    /*display all students*/
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my while loop is only displaying 14 students, when I need it to display all 15. I believe the first student is being lost when I use:

```
$faculty= result->fetch_assoc();
```

However I thought that because my `while` loop is calling on the original `$result` array I wouldn't be affected by this.

Can anyone explain what is happening here? How can I use the same array twice without having to requery my database and without losing that first result?

Comment: Every `$result->fetch_assoc` iterates the result set once. Why not `where field <> 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because each time you call `fetch_assoc` it returns the current row and moves the pointer to the next row. You can use `data_seek` to adjust the result pointer to an arbitrary row in the result:

```
$result->data_seek(0);
```

Your code will look like this:

```
$faculty= $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($faculty['field'] == 1)
    die();
$result->data_seek(0);
while($students = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    /*display all students*/
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You're on fire today Ismail. `data_seek` looks to have done the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to place the result into the faculty variable at all.

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE...";
$result = $db->query($qry);
$if($db->error)die($db->error);
// Check to see if Result is Empty
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo("No Information in Result");
} else {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
  //Do Some Code Here
  //display students with $row variable
  echo($row['student_name'] . "<br />");
  echo($row['student_age']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not just checking to see if my query has returned data. `if(faculty['field']  == 1)` actually checking the value of the field, not just whether it is empty or not.